# Mongodb $unwind says it did not expect an array

Tags: php, mongodb

I am building an application based on MongoDB with PHP.
I have a collection called "parameters" that its documents have, among other things, an array called "included" which contains objects.

I am trying to do an aggregate command that would access a "parameters" document (based on value in variable $gid) and turn each "included" array element into its own document. The goal is to perform further steps in the aggregate pipe, but since the issue I have is with $unwind I am not adding those to here for clarity sake.

```
$results = $collection->aggregate(array(
        array('$match' => array('_id' => new MongoId($gid))),
        array('$project' => array('included' => 1)),
        array('$unwind' => array('$included'))
    ));
```

This works on another similar case in the application, for some reason in this case I'm getting errors.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'MongoResultException' with
>   message 'localhost:27017: expected either a string or an object as
>   specification for $unwind stage, got Array'

The parameters document:

```
db.parameters.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57cd573a216985ced0c66bd2"),
    "name" : "Domains",
    "keywords" : [ ],
    "included" : [
        {
            "instance_id" : ObjectId("57cb2ffd216985ced0c66bcb"),
            "category" : null
        }
    ],
}
```

As noted, it works fine in another scenario (different collections/documents, but the same - an array of documents). For some reason, it's giving me trouble now. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Posting an answer for anyone else who may encounter this, making the same mistake I did. 
The issue was with sending the '$included' value as an array.
Should be:

```
array('$unwind' => '$included')
```